# Getting the values of pgfplots' \addplot outside of the plot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

It is easy to generate plots with some randomness with pgfplots (see code below for a toy example). I would also like to include a table containing the x,y coordinates of the plot in my document, i.e., I would like to get the plotted values. Can this be achieved in a simple fashion?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfmathsetseed{123}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [samples= 10, only marks] {x + rand};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    % Table with the x,y values from addplot here 
\end{document}
```

I am aware that the reverse, i.e., creating the table first, then plotting, can be achieved using pgfplotstable (see below). For my particular case, this seems quite cumbersome, however.

```
\pgfplotstablenew[
    create on use/x/.style={
        create col/expr={
            \pgfplotstablerow 
        }
    },
    create on use/y/.style={
        create col/expr={
            \thisrow{x} + rand
        }
    },
    columns={x,y},
    ]{10}
    \loadedtable
    
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\loadedtable}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [only marks] table {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
``
```

Comment: So effectively you want to generate a bunch of noise and add that to your existing data? It seems to me that a macro that does this for you shouldn't be too complicated and once you have written it, you can simply reuse that and make this job a one-liner. This solution (defining a macro and reusing that) would also work for your `pgfplotstable` approach.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The question would also apply without the noise: Can the values generated by the \addplot function be obtained, stored and then used in LaTeX later? The noise here mainly serves the purpose of illustrating the fact that the exact data generated by \addplot can not be known analytically.

Comment: I assume the data is stored in a CSV file? In that case there are numerous packages that deal with importing this kind of data. Which one is the best for you, depends a bit on what exactly you want to do with the data, but I always found [csvsimple](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) to do a good job at this kind of stuff.

Comment: Ah - or are you perhaps referring to the case where you are giving `pgfplots` a functional expression and the let it evaluate this function at different sample points to generate the plot? In that case, you could simple make use of core PGF functionality (or other calculation-related packages) to compute the values for you and simple create a small loop that loops over your sample points and evaluates your function for each of them.